# Anyone knows the approach to solve such puzzles and the answer to this?

Tags: logical-deduction

[image]

I don't know how to solve such puzzles. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You should have choices with these kind of logical reasoning questions to solve it with a single unique solution.

Comment: If you look at the bottom of the image, something is cut off.

Comment: @dcfyj Probably the choices.

Comment: Obviously this is not your own puzzle, so you should reference where it came from. Plagiarism is a pretty big no-no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically those kinds of problems are too broad as they can have multiple answers. Each of which is just as valid as the last. As such, these puzzles end up being "Guess what I'm thinking".

One possible answer would be 36 because it makes both oval shapes equal to 60. Another possible answer would be 25 because that cause each number set {(14,4),(29,1), (21,3)} to be equal to a multiple of three. I could probably go on.

Anyhow, the moral here is, these are too broad/too vague/not enough information.

Comment: I would go with 36 as the answer :)

Comment: Me too, but it's still too broad. More Math-y people than I could come up with other valid answers